# Split AC unit signal cable connection

Tags: air-conditioning

The signal terminal colors on the indoor unit are red black yellow and green. The signal cable colors are red black white and green. The terminal colors on the outside unit are brown blue black and green. The instructions say to match the colors. I don't find that to be possible. Should I just match terminal 1 2 and 3 from the inside unit to terminal 1 2 and 3 on the outside unit?

Comment: Are you in North America? Europe does things very differently.

Comment: call the manufacturer?

Comment: There should be a wiring diagram in the condenser or the air handler.

Comment: Yes, can you post photos of the wiring diagram in the air handler/indoor unit please?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you are interested in 5 different terminals, and they have names/letters.

Remember: Remember air conditioners are an optional, bolt-on add-on to gas furnaces. It adds a "cold thing" to the furnace's air handling stack, but the furnace doesn't even know it is there.

- Rh = Furnace/24 volt **supply** *from the furnace*
- C = 24 volt return ("neutral" is not the right word) This does not go to the thermostat, unless it is a smart thermostat.
- W = Furnace/**Call for Heat**. When this is connected to Rh, the furnace should fire up, and then the furnace will control its own fan when the heat exchanger is hot enough.
- G = Furnace/**Call for Fan**. When this is connected to Rh, the furnace runs its blower only.
- Y = Air Conditioner/**Call for A/C**.  When this is connected to Rc, the outdoor unit will go SCHRUCK HMMMMMMMM.
- Rc = Rh, but for when the air conditioner has its own 24 volt supply.

The furnace doesn't know it has an air conditioner, so the thermostat's job is to "call for fan" when "calling for A/C".

Now proper thermostat cables come in 2-wire **Red** and **White**, for 3-wire also **Green**, for 4-wire also **Yellow**, for 5-wire also **Cyan**.

Notice carefully.  How the first letter of those colors is exactly the names of the control wires.  That's no accident.

In fact, if you think about the likelihood of needing a particular wire, you see every system uses R and W (which 2-wire has), some with fan control also need G, with A/C need G and Y, and with a smart stat also need C.  *Isn't that clever?*

On the other hand, if you wire the A/C to steal R and C from the furnace, then you only need Y and C out to the outdoor A/C unit.  Do you need 5-wire cable just to get a **yellow** and **cyan** wire?  No, you could use 2-wire red and white wire. **But if you do, then it's *all on you* to keep the colors straight**.

So that's what you must do with that telephone cable. Although really you shouldn't use it, because the wires are thinner than Code requires.

You can re-mark them with colored tape.  If so, always mark both ends of the cable the same, *at the same time*.  Otherwise you'll confuse yourself and make mistakes. BTDT.